# How to retrieve value from a table

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

How to  pull a string from a table (see screenshot) with a custom Js for google tag manager dataLayer.See here :https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtpbO.jpg [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtpbO.jpg)

I tried this

```
function () { 
    document.getElementsByClassName('shop_table order_details');
    return;
}
```

But no way, i always get : undefined
Tks for the help

Answer (score 1):

your function

```
function () { 
    document.getElementsByClassName('shop_table order_details');
    return;
}
```

returns `undefined` always as you made it so. `return;` will always return `undefined`.

and to get value from table cell

#### html

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>some text</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>some text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>some text</th>
            <td>some text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>some text</th>
            <td>your text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>some text</th>
            <td>some text</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

#### js

```
var tfoot = document.getElementsByTagName("tfoot");
var tr = tfoot[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");
console.log(tr[1].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerText);
```

Comment: Hi Venugopal,
`
it just works great . I put the code here for GTM purpose :
{function (){ 
var tfoot = document.getElementsByTagName("tfoot");
var tr = tfoot[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");
return(tr[1].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerText);
}}`

Many thanks ..

Comment: Sorry but i can display the code properly  ...with quotes `` it doesn't show

Comment: you can see upvote arrow, no. of votes, downvote arrow and a gray check mark. check that and it will be marked as accepted answer

Comment: @Venugopal : yes i saw  it ..tks again